# Form and file upload with htmlService and app script not working

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to upload a file to a specific google drive folder along with form data into a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet portion of this code works, but the file upload function does not. Any help on fixing this would be appreciated.

**Code.gs**

```
var submissionSSKey = 'SS ID';
function doGet(e) {
      var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
}

function doPost(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
  var LoanType = template.name = e.parameter.name;
  var borrower = template.department = e.parameter.department;
  var amount = template.message = e.parameter.message;
  var emailed = template.email = e.parameter.email;
  var comp = 'N/A'

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[comp,LoanType,borrower,amount,emailed]]);

  var fileBlob = e.paramater.thefile
  var doc = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder ID');
            doc.createFile(fileBlob)//.rename('New Name');


  return template.evaluate();


}
```

**Form.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="<?= action ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="width: 500px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Name:</td>
    <td>
    <input name="name" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Department:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="department">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option>Cashier</option>
    <option>Greeter</option>
    <option>Runner</option>
    <option>Line Control</option>
    <option>IDB</option>
    <option>Unknown</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Email:</td>
    <td>
    <input name="email" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Message:</td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="message" style="margin: 2px; height: 148px; width: 354px;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p>
    School Schedule (Image Files Only):</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p>
    <input type="file" id="thefile" name="thefile">
    </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td>
    You will receive an email confirmation upon submission</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </form></body>
</html>
```

**Thanks.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Thanks</h1>
    <p>Thank you for your submission.</p>
    Name: <?= name ?><br/>
    Department: <?= department ?><br/>
    Message: <?= message ?><br/>
    Email: <?= email ?><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:** Working example

The HtmlService does not support the `post` method for HTML forms. The input elements collected by a form can be communicated to a server-side function using a handler function instead. For more details, see [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms).

Here's an example based on the code you've posted in your question.

#### Form.html

```
<script>
  // Javascript function called by "submit" button handler,
  // to show results.
  function updateOutput(resultHtml) {
    toggle_visibility('inProgress');
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = resultHtml;
  }
  
  // From blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/
  function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
    else
      e.style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>

<div id="formDiv">
<!-- Form div will be hidden after form submission -->
<form id="myForm">

    Name: <input name="name" type="text" /><br/>
    Department:  <select name="department">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option>Cashier</option>
    <option>Greeter</option>
    <option>Runner</option>
    <option>Line Control</option>
    <option>IDB</option>
    <option>Unknown</option>
    </select><br/>
    Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br/>
    Message: <textarea name="message" style="margin: 2px; height: 148px; width: 354px;"></textarea><br/>
    School Schedule (Image Files Only): <input name="myFile" type="file" /><br/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv'); toggle_visibility('inProgress');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="inProgress" style="display: none;">
<!-- Progress starts hidden, but will be shown after form submission. -->
Uploading. Please wait...
</div>

<div id="output">
  <!-- Blank div will be filled with "Thanks.html" after form submission. -->
</div>
```

#### Thanks.html

```
<div>
    <h1>Thanks</h1>
    <p>Thank you for your submission.</p>
    Name: <?= name ?><br/>
    Department: <?= department ?><br/>
    Message: <?= message ?><br/>
    Email: <?= email ?><br/>
    File URL: <?= fileUrl ?><br/>
</div>
```

#### Code.gs

```
var submissionSSKey = '--Spreadsheet-key--';
var folderId = "--Folder-Id--";

function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
}


function processForm(theForm) {
  var fileBlob = theForm.myFile;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var doc = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  
  // Fill in response template
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
  var name = template.name = theForm.name;
  var department = template.department = theForm.department;
  var message = template.message = theForm.message;
  var email = template.email = theForm.email;     
  var fileUrl = template.fileUrl = doc.getUrl();
  
  // Record submission in spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[name,department,message,email,fileUrl]]);
  
  // Return HTML text for display in page.
  return template.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

---

Original answer, which was focused on basic debugging:

Where does this code come from originally? There have been [multiple questions about it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20is:question%20borrower%20amount), and it might be helpful to see the original tutorial or example it was taken from.

When you run this code as a published web app, and submit a file, the error you receive is `TypeError: Cannot read property "thefile" from undefined.` Without any more digging, this tells you that there's an `undefined` object being used in your code. What object is that? Don't know yet, but a clue is that the code is looking for a property named `"thefile"`.

If you have the script open in the editor, and launched the webapp from there (by clicking on `Test web app for your latest code` in the Publish / Deploy as Web App dialog), then you can also check the Execution Transcript for more details. (under View menu) You'll find it contains something like this:

```
[13-12-25 07:49:12:447 EST] Starting execution
[13-12-25 07:49:12:467 EST] HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile([Thanks.html]) [0 seconds]
[13-12-25 07:49:12:556 EST] SpreadsheetApp.openById([--SSID--]) [0.089 seconds]
[13-12-25 07:49:12:557 EST] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0 seconds]
[13-12-25 07:49:12:626 EST] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.067 seconds]
[13-12-25 07:49:12:627 EST] Sheet.getRange([1, 1, 1, 5]) [0 seconds]
[13-12-25 07:49:12:629 EST] Range.setValues([[[N/A, , Select Option, , ]]]) [0.001 seconds]
[13-12-25 07:49:12:983 EST] Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "thefile" from undefined. (line 20, file "Code") [0.17 seconds total runtime]
```

We see that same error, but now we know the line number. That line contains a spelling mistake:

```
var fileBlob = e.paramater.thefile
                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about the file name from "index" to "form," that was a mistake I made while asking this question. Also, while I feel really stupid for spelling "parameter" wrong, my code is still not working. Here's the execution transcript now:
[13-12-25 08:28:39:067 MST] Execution failed: Cannot find method createFile((class)). (line 23, file "Code") [1.735 seconds total runtime]

Comment: By the way, the code came from of a question a user asked on this site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261247/google-apps-script-create-form-with-file-upload

Comment: Ah, that clears things up a bit - that question was using UiService, while you're using HtmlService for your form. However, you've kept the same server-side post handling. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15457041/1677912) from a member of the GAS team, "HtmlService doesn't even use doPost - it uses the google.script.run syntax exclusively." [This follow up answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15790713/1677912) has an example using HtmlService and server-side handlers to accomplish the equivalent of the UiService POST for a file upload.

Comment: I can get one function working (either the file upload or the spreadsheet data inserted) but I can't get both to run together. For now I'm just sticking with App Script Ui and no HTML.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working example using htmlservice.

Comment: Thanks for that. It works great. Is there an easy way to add another clickhandler type event that shows a loading bar during the upload. I've achieved this on my UiApps fairly easily, but transferring them over to this new setup is still a bit of a challenge for me.

Comment: Probably can't easily create a progress bar, since `google.script.run` provides no progress feedback other than final success. Outside of this environment, you could attach an HTML5 progress tag and catch events from an `XMLHttpRequest`, but those requests to the Google App Server are forbidden.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should've specified a little bit more what I meant by loading bar. In my UiApps I have this code:   `var statusLabel = app.createHorizontalPanel().add(app.createImage('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211279/loading3T.gif')).add(app.createHTML("Uploading. Please wait...")).setId('status').setVisible(false);` It just "enables" on submut click by `.setVisible(true)`, and displays the .gif from that link before the Thank you message comes up.

Comment: No problem, then! In the same way that the form is being hidden after submission, we can use `onClick=` with multiple javascript functions to display a progress `<div>` that starts hidden. I've updated Form.html in the answer to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! The `toggle_visibility` script is a beautiful little tool. I went ahead and added `style="display: block;` to the `id="formDiv"` section so that it would disappear on submit click. It's exactly what I needed. I also added `<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211279/loading3T.gif" alt="Loading">Uploading. Please wait...` to the `id="inProgress"` section