# Google Apps Script: is there some method to select and upload a file from desktop?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there some method to select and upload a file from desktop? I want to create a simple UI that allows me to select a file from desktop, upload it to drive and get it's link. I find [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open), but it's not what I'm wanting (I need to select the files from desktop and not from GDrive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using HtmlService. There's an example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769149/form-and-file-upload-with-htmlservice-and-app-script-not-working/20773061#20773061).

If you prefer the UiService, have a look at [Class FileUpload](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/file-upload). There's an example provided on the documentation page.