# Google Forms file upload complete example

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script, google-forms

How do I allow my viewers to use Google Forms to upload some files to my form and save it to my Google Drive?

I am looking for a complete example: It must tell what code to add to the example Google Form HTML source. How to use Google Apps Script to upload the viewer's file to my Google Drive account?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Google Forms can upload files, but this solution does not use Google Forms.  This answer does not a modify a Google Form, which can't be done.  This is an example that uses a Google Apps Script Web App, which is different than a Google Form.  A Web App functions almost the same as a website, but you can't get a domain name for it.

Apps Script has a service named HTML Service, which is what this code uses.
For the guide see: [Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html?hl=en)

I you want to use an `onsubmit` attribute in the beginning form tag:  `<form onsubmit="myFunctionName()">`, it will cause the Web App to disappear from the screen after the form submission.

If you are using a "submit" type HTML button, and want to continue to use it, you can try adding `event.preventDefault();` to your code in the submit event handler function in order to keep the browser tab from trying to load different HTML.  Or you'll need to use the `google.script.run` client side API.

---

A custom form for uploading files from a users computer drive, to your Google Drive can be created with the Apps Script HTML Service. This example requires writing a program, but I've provide all the basic code here.

This example shows an upload form with Google Apps Script HTML Service.

## What You Need

- Google Account
- Google Drive
- Google Apps Script - also called Google Script

[Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com)

There are various ways to end up at the Google Apps Script code editor.

- Load Apps Script directly from the web address:   https://script.google.com
- Open a Google Sheet first, then open Apps Script
- Go to your Google Drive, then Open Apps Script:  https://drive.google.com/drive/#my-drive
- Go to your Google Drive, then click on an Apps Script project file
- Open Apps Script from Google Docs
- etc

I mention this because if you are not aware of all the possibilities, it could be a little confusing.  Google Apps Script can be embedded in a Google Site, Sheets, Docs or Forms, or used as a stand alone app.

[Apps Script Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

This example is a "Stand Alone" app with HTML Service.

HTML Service - Create a web app using HTML, CSS and Javascript

Google Apps Script only has two types of files inside of a `Project`:

- Script
- HTML

Script files have a `.gs` extension.  The `.gs` code is a server side code written in JavaScript, and a combination of Google's own API.

- Copy and Paste the following code
- Save It
- Create the first Named Version
- Publish it
- Set the Permissions

  and you can start using it.

### Start by:

- Create a new Blank Project in Apps Script
- Copy and Paste in this code:

### Upload a file with HTML Service:

***Code.gs*** file  (Created by Default)

```
//For this to work, you need a folder in your Google drive named:
// 'For Web Hosting'
// or change the hard coded folder name to the name of the folder
// you want the file written to

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form')
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
    .setTitle('Name To Appear in Browser Tab');
}

function processForm(theForm) {
  var fileBlob = theForm.picToLoad;
  
  Logger.log("fileBlob Name: " + fileBlob.getName())
  Logger.log("fileBlob type: " + fileBlob.getContentType())
  Logger.log('fileBlob: ' + fileBlob);

  var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById(Your Folder ID);
    fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob);
    
  return true;
}
```

***Create an html file:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="main-heading">Main Heading</h1>
    <br/>
    <div id="formDiv">

      <form id="myForm">
    
        <input name="picToLoad" type="file" /><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="picUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
          
      </form>
    </div>


  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  <!-- div will be filled with innerHTML after form submission. -->
  Uploading. Please wait...
</div>

</body>
<script>

function picUploadJs(frmData) {

  document.getElementById('status').style.display = 'inline';

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
    .processForm(frmData)
};
  // Javascript function called by "submit" button handler,
  // to show results.
  
  function updateOutput() {
  
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = "The File was UPLOADED!";
  }

</script>
</html>
```

This is a full working example.  It only has two buttons and one `<div>` element, so you won't see much on the screen.  If the `.gs` script is successful, true is returned, and an `onSuccess` function runs.  The onSuccess function (updateOutput) injects inner HTML into the `div` element with the message, "The File was UPLOADED!"

- Save the file, give the project a name
- Using the menu: `File`, `Manage Version` then Save the first Version
- `Publish`, `Deploy As Web App`  then Update

When you run the Script the first time, it will ask for permissions because it's saving files to your drive.  After you grant permissions that first time, the Apps Script stops, and won't complete running.  So, you need to run it again.  The script won't ask for permissions again after the first time.

The Apps Script file will show up in your Google Drive.  In Google Drive you can set permissions for who can access and use the script.  The script is run by simply providing the link to the user.  Use the link just as you would load a web page.

Another example of using the HTML Service can be seen at this link here on StackOverflow:

[File Upload with HTML Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769149/form-and-file-upload-with-htmlservice-and-app-script-not-working?rq=1)

Here is a link to a shared Apps Script Web App file with an input form:

[Shared File - Contact Form](https://script.google.com/d/125dG42eB9lM4SPq64p0dpR2CBH4ohfHiqu9TvFNM8s4Ra7pt-7kHXoTM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: that was a great answer.   I just searched for the Forms+ add-on, but could not find it in forms or sheets.   Could you send a direct link to it.

Comment: When I run the code, it says.. No HTML file named Form.html was found. (line 7, file "")

Comment: Remove the file extension from the file name.  It's not needed.  I just updated the answer.  Don't know why the `.html` file extension was in there.

Comment: Where can I get the ID of the folder? Is the name the same as the ID??

Comment: I created a folder called Images in My Drive and changed this code `var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById(Your Folder ID);` to var `fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById('Images');` but it gives the error `No Item with the given ID could be found or you do not have permission to access it` on the console

Comment: That's really nice and simple. Thank you very much Sandy! But I still have a question: how can I embed this script to a Google Form? When I click at Tools > Script Editor... it opens a new project (which I used your code), but I can't insert it into my Form.

Comment: You can't embed this in a Google Form.  This code is for a Stand Alone Web App.  You must publish the project a Web App.  Choose, "Publish" and then "Deploy as Web App".  This is an HTML form, not a Google Form.  A Web App is basically like a web site, but you can't map a domain name to the URL.

Comment: Right Sandy. I thought I could add it to a Google Form too, like an add on. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: But is there no way to add it to an existing Google Form ??

Comment: Custom HTML and CSS can't be added to a Google Form.  Client Side JavaScript can not be added to a Google Form either.  You *can* embed an Apps Script Web App into a Google Site though.

Comment: To clarify this for people who read this article further - you actually can not use this example with Google Forms, but there is a work around with Google Site in which you have to do the whole job from scratch?

Comment: Nice script.  Thanks.

Comment: Should be updated as "**Upload**" question type is **now supported in Google Forms for all users**:  https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/07/new-features-in-google-forms.html

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2016, Google has added a file upload question type in native Google Forms, no Google Apps Script needed. [See documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7322334?hl=en&ref_topic=6063584).

Comment: I have a file upload question in my google form, and I want to submit a response to it using my Unity game (C#). I am able to submit the response to other questions through my app but not able to do so for the file upload. Please help!

Comment: Please note: respondents need to be signed in to a Google Account