# How to transform a google form to Html Service

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form with a lot of items in it, including many page breaks.

However unfortunately google doesn't allow yet to upload files by google forms, but it possible to do so by Html Service.

The issue is that its a lot of work for me to transofrm manually the existing form to html service.

Is there a way to do it automatically by google app script code ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013693/google-forms-file-upload-complete-example

Comment: Its not a duplicate at all !! I know the question above and it even worked for me. The problem is that I have to rewrite again my existing google form instead of copy it (some how) to an html service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at FormFuse (was at formfuse.io). You give it a Google Form and it emails you back with the HTML/CSS version that you can customise to your hearts content! I've found it very useful when you start hitting the limitations of Google Forms.

**Update 5 Jan 2017** - It looks like FormFuse has been discontinued, presumably because of the new Google Forms. Post a comment if you find an alternative service.

Comment: The link is broken.