# Anonymous upload go Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So I'm trying to follow [this blog post](http://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files) to allow anonymous users to upload files to a particular folder in my Google Drive. The idea is to have this sitting on a website. The idea is that I will then be able to use those files from Google Drive (i.e., not actually putting together a web app, I just want a method to upload files from a simple webpage).

Without any changes to what's mentioned on the blog, I get the form I should be getting, I fill it in, and select "Upload". The "Upload" button turns into "Uploading", and that's all. No files are created in the destination folder, and the webpage just hangs there. Is there something I'm missing here?

[After some more trial and error] I note that if I log out of my Google account on Chrome (e.g. Incognito Window), everything works flawlessly. Firefox seems to work well too. Maybe this is a problem to do with the browser, rather than GAS?

Comment: Take a look at this StackOverflow post: [Google File Upload Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013693/google-forms-file-upload-complete-example)

Comment: Did you authorize the server-side code, by running any function in the debugger for instance? Looks like @amit-agarwal left that step out of the blog.

Comment: @SandyGood I had already taken notice of that post, but it's an excellent overview