# Google Sites - Using Forms

Tags: form-submit, google-sites

I am building a Google Sites page with a simple form in which you can upload attachments. How would I go about having users fill out a form and attach a .jpeg that would automatically add the new jpeg file to the home page?

Thank you!

Comment: Now it's possible for any Google accounts: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/google-forms-file-upload-feature

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can attach a .jpeg file to a google form, i am on similar project.
BUT! You can make a special form created by HTML and JavaScript, where you can add the file submit button. It took me days before i got it but to help you i show you where i started:

[Google Forms file upload complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013693/google-forms-file-upload-complete-example)

It is an asked question about similar topic.

http://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/

This is the page, where i finaly understood what is going on.

Just by the way. You will have to do a lot more scripting than that. This are only ideas where to start. I am working now on the uploading to the google site.

If you have anymore problems, please contact me. I can show you the source codes i am working on right now.

Have a nice day and good luck with sripting ;)