# Uploading Image to Google Forms

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-forms

[google forms file upload complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013693/google-forms-file-upload-complete-example/30766456#30766456) 
In reference to this question and excellent answer by Sandy Good.  Since my question on the post itself was immediately deleted because reasons, I'll ask it here.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows if it's still working. I did everything it says, and it all seems to be working: it gets to the point of "Uploading. Please wait..." but then just stays there forever. No files are created, and nothing changes.

I can post the code I've got, but it's identical to what Sandy wrote, except for changing the name of the folder from YOUR FOLDER ID.

I've created the directory as prescribed "For Web Hosting", but it won't upload.
Did Google break this intentionally, or have I messed something up?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, in case anyone else sees this in 2 years...
It was of course expecting a folder ID, and not the name of a folder.  I ended up having to grab folder names that matched it, and since I made sure it was unique enough, I iterated through the collection of 1 folder it returned and used that.