# Push notifications for Directory changes

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is it possible for me to setup an app which is installable by other organisations which send push notifications to a specific URL for directory changes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can setup an app that can be that can be used outside your organization. Just make sure that when deploying, make sure to allow "Anyone"

As for sending push notifications for directory changes (Drive)

> Google Apps Script is no longer a viable platform for implementing Google API Push Notifications across most services (Drive, Calendar, Admin Directory etc.). If you want to stick with Google's cloud offerings, there are alternatives you can explore. Google Cloud Functions is one such option.

#### Reference:

- [Google Apps Script - Sharing outside of domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30933491/14606045)
- [Drive API Push Notifications for a Google Apps Script Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60635527/14606045)