# HTML/CSS form: Jquery plugin validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to improve this answer [upload file/google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769149/form-and-file-upload-with-htmlservice-and-app-script-not-working) in order to use it. I've managed more or less to change the design. I'm trying now to make the values required and the form cannot be submitted until all the values are valid/present

I'm using google script editor to publish the form: I've got 3 files: Code.gs; Form.html and Thnaks.html

I've managed to do the following (advise of Daemedeor)

```js
<script>
  // Javascript function called by "submit" button handler,
  // to show results.
  function updateOutput(resultHtml) {
    toggle_visibility('inProgress');
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = resultHtml;
  }

  // From blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/
  function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
    else
      e.style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
  * Basic jQuery Validation Form Demo Code
  * Copyright Sam Deering 2012
  * Licence: http://www.jquery4u.com/license/
  */
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#register-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    name: "required",
                    department: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    
                },
                messages: {
                    name: "Please enter your name",
                    department: "Please choose your department",
                    
                    },
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

```css
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">

img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width:500px;
      height:170px;
     ;
}

form {
    width:450px;
    padding:30px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

h1 {
    background: #2A88AD;
    padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;
    margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    border: 1px solid #257C9E;
}

h1 > span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

label {
    display: block;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #888;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="file"],
textarea,
select {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
}

section{
    font: normal 20px 'Bitter', serif;
    color: #2A88AD;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

section span {
    background: #2A88AD;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: -45px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

input[type="button"], 
input[type="submit"]{
    background: #2A88AD;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
    border: 1px solid #257C9E;
    font-size: 15px;
}
input[type="button"]:hover, 
input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background: #2A6881;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
}


</style>
```

```html
<div id="formDiv">
<!-- Form div will be hidden after form submission -->
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
<h1>Job Application<span>Apply now and get the opportunity to join us!</span></h1>
<section> <span>1</span>Personal details</section>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    <section> <span>2</span>Your experience</section>
    Department:  <select name="department">
    <option>Math</option>
    <option>English</option>
    <option>French</option>
    <option>Science Control</option>
    <option>Art</option>
    </select><br/>
<section> <span>3</span>Contact</section>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com"/><br/>
    Message: <textarea name="message"></textarea><br/>
<section> <span>4</span>Attachment</section>
    CV: <input type="file" name="myFile"/><br/>
    Qualification: <input type="file" name="myFile2"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply"
      onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv'); toggle_visibility('inProgress');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" /><br/>
</form>
</div>

<div id="inProgress" style="display: none;">
<!-- Progress starts hidden, but will be shown after form submission. -->
Uploading. Please wait...
</div>

<div id="output">
  <!-- Blank div will be filled with "Thanks.html" after form submission. -->
</div>
```

and here is Code.gs

```js
var submissionSSKey = '1Ed05-havA-Lw-BpYWhYf8Ib7u77oevW3mFZ8m1vQ8HU';
var folderId = "0B2MoK-dDGTVDfkpXNnZvVUhBWlhLZGIxN2Qzcm40WGhJVC0xUzNSbTRiUW04SkdQTG9ncEU";

function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
}


function processForm(theForm) {
  var fileBlob = theForm.myFile;
  var fileBlob2 = theForm.myFile2;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var doc = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  var doc2 = folder.createFile(fileBlob2);


  // Fill in response template
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
  var name = template.name = theForm.name;
  var department = template.department = theForm.department;
  var message = template.message = theForm.message;
  var email = template.email = theForm.email;     
  var fileUrl = template.fileUrl = doc.getUrl();
  var fileUrl2 = template.fileUrl = doc2.getUrl();

  // Record submission in spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[name,department,message,email,fileUrl,fileUrl2]]);

  // Return HTML text for display in page.
  return template.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

when adding the script of jquery, (I don't know if the code is properly formatted first, i've done my best) the form is submitted though certain values are not valid

Thank you for any suggestion or help

Comment: your form isn't id'd with: #register-form so replace that with #myForm, don't submit onclick so change <input type='submit'> to <input type='button'>

Comment: Thank you, I've done that $("#myForm").validate also change to button, but still submitting?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're checking its submitting but if you tie in the toggle to the onclick event and are checking that way, then it'll still toggle it, so you should toggle until after the validation is submitting the form

Comment: I'm checking on the google spreadsheet, if I write only the name for instance and leave the other values empty, I'll receive the name and after submitting and there is the thanks message also: try it: [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxkgQJwQy3xS8Z4ksnnVjk-MKLOP0CQtZ-41lkAjXKvduc5Tn0/exec)