# Show a link at return in script.gs

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made a form that uploads files to a folder in Google Drive, but i'd like that once the file has be uploaded to show a message including a link to click on, something like this:

```
return "Image uploaded, please click here: https://www.google.com" ;
```

How do I make that `https://www.google.com` becomes a link you could click on?

Comment: To make a clickable link, you'll have to use the HTML Service to generate a dialog box or sidebar:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Comment: Right you can use HTML Service, Please Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769149/form-and-file-upload-with-htmlservice-and-app-script-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To create a web app with the HTML service, your code must include a **doGet()** function that tells the script how to serve the page. The function must return an [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) object. An HtmlOutput object that can be served from a script. Due to security considerations, scripts cannot directly return HTML to a browser. Instead, they must sanitize it so that it cannot perform malicious actions. You can return sanitized HTML like this:

```
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
 }
```

The HTML service can display a dialog or sidebar in Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms if your script is container-bound to the file.

A script that creates a user interface for a document, spreadsheet, or form does not need a `doGet()` function specifically, and you do not need to save a version of your script or deploy it. Instead, the function that opens the user interface must pass your HTML file as an HtmlOutput object to the `showModalDialog())` or `showSidebar()` methods of the Ui object for the active document, form, or spreadsheet.

Here's a sample code of function `doGet()`:

```
function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   // Creates a link to your favorite search engine.
   var anchor = app.createAnchor("a link", "http://www.google.com");
   app.add(anchor);
   return app;
 }
```